# How to use CORS with JSON Response in Compojure?

Tags: clojure, cors, compojure, ring

I am creating a simple API which returns `JSON` data back to the user. For development purposes, I would like to enable CORS so that my `react` frontend can call the API locally. For the moment, it complains

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3001' is therefore not allowed access.

**Question**: How can I use [ring-cors](https://github.com/r0man/ring-cors) (or something similar) to enable CORS and send back JSON data?

**Observations**: With the current `(app ..)`, `(wrap-cors ...)` provides no cross origin header.

I have tried several variations of the order but none seem to work. For instance, `(wrap cors ...)` followed by `(wrap-defaults ...)` doesn't work.

**MWE**

```
(ns qitab-api.handler
  (:require [compojure.core :refer :all]
            [compojure.route :as route]
            [ring.middleware.defaults :refer [wrap-defaults site-defaults]]
            [ring.middleware.json :refer [wrap-json-response wrap-json-body]]
            [ring.middleware.cors :refer [wrap-cors]]
            [ring.util.response :as r]))

(defroutes app-routes
   (GET "/" []
     (r/response {:hello "World!!"}))
   (route/not-found "Not Found"))

(def app
  (-> app-routes
      wrap-json-body
      wrap-json-response
     (wrap-defaults site-defaults)
     (wrap-cors :access-control-allow-origin [#".*"] :access-control-allow-
     headers [:get])))
```

P.S. I have looked at several other questions which relate to CORS and Compojure however, none of them deal with the JSON aspect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`:access-control-allow-headers` should be `:access-control-allow-methods`. Then it should work.